# $_SESSION unset issue

Tags: php, session

I have a bizzare case where a session variable is being unset. It seems to be being caused by the following line:

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") unset($_SESSION["search"]);
```

Whereas if I remove the unset() in the if clause it works fine. The curious thing is echo some arbitrary text in place of the unset(), nothing comes out (indicating its all fine).

Can anyone see any possible issues with the above line that might cause the $_SESSION to still be unset, bearing in mind that $_SESSION['search'] is actually an array (and sometimes multidimensional)??

EDIT:

```
include SERVER_ROOT.'/classes/session.class.php';
$sess = new Session();
session_start();
```

For example the following will echo out 'hallelujah':

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") ;
if(isset($_SESSION["search"])) echo 'hallelujah';
```

But this will not (and the if statement evaluates as false):

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") unset($_SESSION["search"]);
if(isset($_SESSION["search"])) echo 'hallelujah';
```

Comment: Your question is a bit tough to understand. If your problem is that `$_SESSION` is empty, usually you've forgotten to call `session_start()` first.

Comment: I know its a difficult one to describe, session_start is most definately being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my bad, this was actually something to do with the 404 page and htaccess redirects. In effect the 404 page included the same code, and was somehow being included by the htaccess file, which was in turn unsetting the $_SESSION value. Curious, but there wasn't anything wrong with the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") unset($_SESSION["search"]);
if(isset($_SESSION["search"])) echo 'hallelujah';
```

IF the first condition is true, it unsets 'search'. Which means the second condition won't fire, which is why you aren't echoing anything. What seems to be the problem here?

**EDIT**

Added some more debug after a comment

```
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php")
```

What's printed when you put this? Is it TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: yea but my point is that the if statement evaluates as false. In both cases. If I test this by putting defining a variable within this statement, then the variable is obviously not defined. So, any ideas why the unset() is apparently acted upon?

Comment: you mean the first IF is false? See my edit and tell me what results you get

Comment: var_dump returns bool(false).

Comment: the bizare thing is this only happens on one of our server implementations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding braces and checking. Could be a weird scope issue. `if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") {var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php"); unset($_SESSION["search"]);}`. If you have a debugger, run that.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried braces. Will have to get a debugger running, anything you could recommend?

Comment: I use xdebugger. It's very easy to setup with eclipse. This article walks you through it : http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803-Introducing-xdebug

Answer (score 0):

`unset()` doesn't care if the value is an array or multidimensional - it will unset it.

Comment: thats what I assumed, I just can't figure out why this line is still being acted upon when the if nothing is passing through the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Tried commenting out the whole line? I am not sure what purpose it is serving given the context.

Comment: yea it works if I comment out the whole line but I kinda need it to reset search values when not on the search page

Comment: Try using a variable in this case.
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != "/search.php") isASearch = true;

Comment: yea well still confusing me, when I'm on /search.php the value is always false when I'm not on this page the value is always true. So why is the unset($_SESSION) behaving differently?? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. What happens and what should happen instead? Here is what your code does: If you are not on search.php then you remove the key `search` and its value from the array `$_SESSION`. Care to describe in similar words what you perceive as a problem?

Comment: You are right, if I am not on search.php then the key 'search' is removed from the $_SESSION. However, the confusing bit is that on on of our servers this implmentation removes the 'search' key even when we are on the search.php

Comment: try var_dumping the session array before and after the if. Make sure you do not have if (); unset() seems to be a common mistake here. Other problem can be -- and the dump will show that your session handler is simply broken.